# phpdesktop - ajax request - resource not found

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, axios, phpdesktop

I am attempting to create a simple application with laravel and wrapping it in phpdesktop to use locally without the need of a webserver(aside from the built-in php server).

Everything works great except this one thing.

If I launch the app.exe, i get 404's when vue/axios requests data from an endpoint, eg: /api/resource.
However, If I open the app in a browser while running the php server (localhost:8000) the resource is found and loaded correctly.

Is there a way around this? Or is this simply how phpdesktop is supposed to work?

Here are a few relavant settings from 'settings.json'

```
"web_server": {
    "listen_on": ["127.0.0.1", 0],
    "www_directory": "www/public",
    "index_files": ["index.html", "index.php"],
    "cgi_interpreter": "php/php-cgi.exe",
    "cgi_extensions": ["php"],
    "cgi_temp_dir": "",
    "404_handler": "/index.php",
    "hide_files": []
},
```

Comment: Adding some code would greatly increase the chance someone could offer you some advice.

Comment: See how to configure laravel with phpdesktop: https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/PHP-frameworks-support#laravel

Comment: @PatrickSteele If my problem was actually related to an issue with my code, I would have. I know it isn't because everything works when not using the phpdesktop executable. ;)

Comment: @CzarekTomczak Everything is configured as you specified.

Comment: What kind of requests are these? Mongoose web server only supports GET/POST. Enable debug console and see what logs say when these urls are accessed, see the Settings wiki page.